# Php Redirect with multiple session variable

Tags: php, session, variables, redirect, header

I'm try to redirect to another page with multiple session variables. However i can only achieve this with one variable. Below is the code i am using:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET["Coid"])) {
$_SESSION["Coid"] = $_GET["Coid"];
};
if (isset($_GET["Cid"])) {
$_SESSION["Cid"] = $_GET["Cid"];
};
if (isset($_GET["Rid"])) {
$_SESSION["Rid"] = $_GET["Rid"];
};
header('Location: http://www.example.com/Admin/Home.php?Cid='.$_SESSION["Coid"]);
die();
?>
```

The above works as intended, however how would i go about adding another session variable to it ?

Thanks.

Comment: By using session you don't need to pass the parameters via URL. So you set the session variables like you do in your script and then redirect to another page (without parameters in URL), that calls `session_start()` and subsequently uses `$_SESSION['Coid']`, `$_SESSION['Cid']` and `$_SESSION['Rid']` values.

Comment: Is the destination of your redirect on the same server ? If it is, you can just redirect without other variables and fetch from the session on the `home.php`.

Comment: If you have stored values in `session` then why are you sending them in url. you can get those values on other page from session

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/Admin/Home.php?Cid='.$_SESSION["Coid"] . "&Rid=" . $_SESSION["Rid"] . "&Coid=" . $_SESSION["Coid"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Query string building](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_GET["Coid"])) {
        $_SESSION["Coid"] = $_GET["Coid"];
    };
    if (isset($_GET["Cid"])) {
        $_SESSION["Cid"] = $_GET["Cid"];
    };
    if (isset($_GET["Rid"])) {
        $_SESSION["Rid"] = $_GET["Rid"];
    };
    $data = array(
        "Cid"  => $_SESSION["Cid"],
        "Coid" => $_SESSION["Coid"],
        "Rid"  => $_SESSION["Rid"]
    );
    $queryString = http_build_query($data);

    header('Location: http://www.example.com/Admin/Home.php?'.$queryString);
    die();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: @Ciruis If you used my answer please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with the following code:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/Admin/Home.php?Coid=".$_GET['Coid']."&Cid=".$_GET['Cid']."&Rid=".$_GET['Rid']);
```